# Mail Server download help

Tags: java, imap, jakarta-mail, mail-server

Is there any mail server, which can use with javamail, simple in operating, having POP3, IMAP, and SMTP support? I know James, but it doesn't provide support for IMAP. Is anybody know?

Comment: you may use javamail with any standards (POP3, IMAP, SMTP) compliant mail server

Answer (score 0):

If hosting on Windows OS is OK, you can give this a try:
http://www.hmailserver.com/

Though your question is more suited for ServerFault or SuperUser.

Answer (score 0):

[Dovecot](http://www.dovecot.org/) works well for POP3 and IMAP and is free/opensource.